# Installing xdebug in terminal

Tags: php, linux, unix, terminal, xdebug

This may be a dumb question but step4 says:
The instructions should look something like:

1) Download xdebug-2.4.0.tgz (I like to use wget -O ~/downlaods/xdebug-2.4.0.tgz http://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-2.4.0.tgz on Ubuntu)

2) Unpack the downloaded file with tar -xvzf xdebug-2.4.0.tgz

3) Run: cd xdebug-2.4.0

4) Run: phpize (See the Xdebug FAQ if you don’t have phpize.)

Currently i've downloaded and unzipped it on my server following these instructions. and then it says cd into the xdebug-2.4.0 folder but what does run mean.. how do i run it? step four and five are confusing.

How do i run debug?

My output:

```
[~/public_html/xdebug-2.4.0]$ phpize
grep: /usr/local/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/local/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/local/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:        
Zend Module Api No:     
Zend Extension Api No:
```

---

I read that i have to sudo apt-get install php5-dev
but everytime i try i get this error message.

apt-get: command not found

Comment: run means run :D Type `cd folder` and `phpize` in the terminal console. They should have said: "execute"

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone, thanks for that but now i have a new problem... do you mind assisting... i posted the next portion above.

Comment: Which linux distribution are you running?

Comment: You mentioned Ubuntu... `apt-get` should be known. You could also try `aptitude` instead. Btw: I've installed PHP7+xdebug from dotdeb.org repositories and I get periodical updates.

Comment: Red Hat has RPM based package management. You will need to utilize [yum](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-yum.html) for managing installations.

Comment: Okay, great! I'll try that now... unzip it in the root folder or where my project is? or does it matter?

Comment: When you could solve your installation problems, please delete your question since it does not belong to programming. You could get better help on the site serverfault.

Comment: yum should be preinstalled as a core tool of Red Hat distribution. But I'm not familiar with Red Hat anymore. They might have changed their packet management system over the years.

Comment: See [RPM manual](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-rpm.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111582/discussion-between-quasimodos-clone-and-thismethod).

Answer (score -2):

I don't know much about what to do. I'm looking for info.
But to make **apt-get work** I've found those steps:

```
sudo su
cd /usr/ports/sysutils/apt/ && make install clean
```

More info [here](http://www.freshports.org/sysutils/apt/)

Hope that hepls and sorry for the bad english